# Eliminar elementos de un ArrayList

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

Éste es mi primer post.

Estoy  realizando un proyecto donde debo crear un `ArrayList` que guarde datos de usuarios **(nombre, edad etc)** a través de un menú. Aquí se aplica el concepto de **Herencia** donde **Estudiante hereda sus atributos a Pagos**. Luego de crear `x` cantidad de usuarios, existe la posibilidad de borrar elementos del `ArrayList` ingresando el número de `array` a eliminar.

El problema es que luego de eliminar efectivamente un elemento, a la hora de seleccionar el método para ver todos los objetos creados, arroja un error el cual es el siguiente:

[image: error]

También adjunto el método y la opción del  menú.

```
if (p!=null) {
    System.out.println(" --- Eliminar alumno --- \n");
    System.out.print("Indique posición de alumno a eliminar: ");
    posicionArray=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    e.eliminarAlumno(posicionArray);
    est.remove(posicionArray);
} else {
    System.out.println(" >>> No hay datos ingresados <<< \n");
}
```

```
public void eliminarAlumno(int posicionArray){
    if (posicionArray >= 0){
        System.out.println(" >>> Registro eliminado <<<\n");
    } else{
        System.out.println(" >>> No se ha encontrado registro <<<\n");
    }
}
```

Destaco lo siguiente:

> Cuando se ingresan los datos de usuario, automáticamente se activa un contador del `array`, que sería el que uso para indicar cuál quiero eliminar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad de stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que no le tomes foto al código, escribelo directamente en tu pregunta, de este modo, es más fácil ayudarte, debido a que, podemos copiar el código para probarlo y darte un mayor soporte al problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La excepción [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) te está ocurriendo porqué el tamaño máximo de la lista es `2` y cuando el usuario escriba como posición el número `2`, es donde provocará un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) (en este caso, te pasó esto porqué se ingresó un índice mayor a `1`) y como veras, este tema es delicado, debido a que, este error puede provocar sobreescritura de memoria del propio programa o incluso, llegar a ocurrir una [falla de segmentación](https://codeday.me/es/qa/20181201/1913.html) en algún espacio de memoria que el programa no tiene acceso, por esa razón, la máquina virtual de Java, no dejará que el desbordamiento se lleve a cabo y ese sería el motivo del porqué se lanza la excepción.

Entonces, debes validar que el usuario solo pueda ingresar una posición que esté en el rango de `0` a `N-1`, es decir, el índice no puede coincidir con `N` (tamaño máximo del arreglo), porqué los índices/posiciones se empieza a contar desde `0`, esta sería la razón del porqué se le debe restar menos uno al tamaño del arreglo.

Una posible solución, es lograr que el método `eliminarAlumno` retorne `true`, si la posición está en el rango de `0` a `size-1`, de lo contrario, devolverá un `false`. Adicionalmente, tendremos que añadirle al método un parámetro extra, ya que, al momento de invocar al método, tendremos que pasar el tamaño de la lista y de esta manera, es como detectamos si la posición es correcta o no

```
public boolean eliminarAlumno(int posicionArray, int size)
{
    if (posicionArray>=0 && posicionArray <= (size-1)) 
    {
        System.out.println(" >>> Registro eliminado <<<\n");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(" >>> No se ha encontrado registro <<<\n");
    }
    return false;
}
```

La forma de llamar/invocar este método, sería de esta manera:

```
if (p!=null) 
{
  System.out.println(" --- Eliminar alumno --- \n");
  System.out.print("Indique posición de alumno a eliminar: ");
  posicionArray=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  if(e.eliminarAlumno(posicionArray, est.size()))
    est.remove(posicionArray);
}
else
{
  System.out.println(" >>> No hay datos ingresados <<< \n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOutOfBonusException` especifica que estas intentando acceder a un miembro del `ArrayList` que no existe. Por ejemplo intentar acceder a la posición 10 de n array con 9 elementos.

En todo caso, deberias de validar la posicion que deseas borrar con una condición:

```
if(posicionArray > ArrayList.Count()-1 )
    //imprimir mensaje de index fuera del limite
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.

Sin embargo, no me sale la sentencia de **ArrayList.Count()** , estoy pensando que puede ser por la versión de Netbeans que uso (8.2)

¿Se le conoce con otro nombre?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que en el caso de los `ArrayList` no se usa `count()` sino mas bien `size()`

Comment: Tu código no funcionará. Si la variable `posicionArray` toma valores negativos, tu condición dará como resultado un `false` y lanzará la excepción.

Comment: Una disculpa, no desconozco mchas funciones de Java , soy mas de C#, pero siempre hay un equivalente.

Answer (score 1):

para poder obtener el valor y luego eliminar el indice correspondiente debes usar remove como lo hiciste pero el metodo eliminar solo valida para dar el mensaje correspondiente a cada caso y lo hace bien pero, si el indice no se encuentra dentro del rango especificado desde 0 hasta array.size()-1 te lanza la excepcion ya que independientemente del numero siempre lo intenta eliminar.

Para solucionar el problema deberias ingresar el
`est.remove(posicionArray);`
dentro del metodo eliminar para mostrar el mensaje y ser eliminado y borrando la instruccion del if (p!=null) para poder validar y ejecutar la linea solo cuando el indice dado esta dentro del rango de la lista.

Otra solucion que puedes usar es validar dentro del if:

```
if (p!=null) 
{
  System.out.println(" --- Eliminar alumno --- \n");
  System.out.print("Indique posición de alumno a eliminar: ");
  posicionArray=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

  // Aqui se valida para ser eliminado, mostrando el mensaje correspondiente en
  // cada caso
  if (validarPosicion(est, posicionArray))
      est.remove(posicionArray);
}
else
{
  System.out.println(" >>> No hay datos ingresados <<< \n");
}
```

Y posteriormente creando una funcion, con tu mismo codigo puedes validar que sea posible la eliminacion de la lista:

```
boolean validarPosicion(ArrayList lista, int posicionArray) {
        if (posicionArray>=0 && posicionArray<lista.size()) 
        {
            System.out.println(" >>> Registro eliminado <<<\n");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(" >>> No se ha encontrado registro <<<\n");
            return false;
        }
}
```